# jsf composite -> ajax listener throws Exception

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jsf-2

**Mojarra: 2.1.26**

**Description:**

I have very simple composite component *hello.xhtml*:

```html
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="value" />    
    <composite:attribute name="changeListener" method-signature="void listener(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <h:inputText id="inputNameId" value="#{cc.attrs.value}">
        <f:ajax execute="@this" event="change" listener="#{cc.attrs.changeListener}"/>
    </h:inputText>
</composite:implementation>
```

As you see implementation is very simple. The main key here is ajax support for event change.

omposite component is used like that:

```html
<h:form id="formId">
        <hla:hello id="compositeId" value="#{helloController.name}"  changeListener="#{helloController.nameChangedListener}">
        </hla:hello>    
</h:form>
```

As you see attrbiute *changeListener* is used. I just want to have listener called. In composite component method-signature is provided. Let's look at backing bean, which is very simple:

```java
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class HelloController implements Serializable{

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void nameChangedListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
    System.out.println("-nameChangedListener-");
    System.out.println("\tphase: " + event.getPhaseId());
}
```

}

Listener method doesn't do anything special, just to keep this simple.

**Problem:**

When I try to run this code I always get Exception:

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException: 0
...

If I change method-signature in my composite component to:

```java
<composite:attribute name="changeListener" method-signature="void listener()" />
```

and method in backing bean to:

```java
public void nameChangedListener(){ ... }
```

everything works fine.

**Question:**

Is there any chance to make it work with AjaxBehaviorEvent as a  listener method parameter?
How to do that?

Comment: Just FYI, it works with MyFaces. I suppose this is a bug in Mojarra.

Comment: @lu4242, this is a very useful information for me. Thank you for your effort to check this.